# Heap block modified past requested size of 2 Error in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, heap-memory

So the following code is causing an error:

```
// free pointers created with malloc
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (rt_offset_rs[i] != NULL ) {
        free(rt_offset_rs[i]); // <== AT THiS LINE
    }
```

ERROR: 
Heap block at 0000000000331DD0 modified at 0000000000331DE2 past requested size of 2

I don't understand this error at all.
The following is the code where I manipulate the pointer rt_offset_rs:

```
            char** rt_offset_rs; 
    rt_offset_rs = malloc(3 * sizeof(char*));
    if (rt_offset_rs == NULL ) {
        fprintf(outputFilePointer, "no more memory");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        rt_offset_rs[i] = malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
        if (rt_offset_rs[i] == NULL ) {
            fprintf(outputFilePointer, "no more memory");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is not with the `free()` call, but somewhere before that, only your system checks for overflows only at some cases, one of them is `free`, and not in each write to the buffer.

It is not part of your code, but it seems that you allocate two bytes, and writes at least 3 to the buffer ( if it is a string - don't forget null terminator is another byte )

Comment: I see what you mean and I changed all of them to 3 but it does not fix my problem. But thank you

Comment: If you show more relevant code, we might be able to help more.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when I do something like following.

```
#include <malloc.h>
int main()
{
    const char* s = "123";
    void** p = (void**)malloc(1);
    *p = (void*)s;
    free(p);
}
```

The code invokes the following error in a **x64** build:

> HEAP[XXX.exe]: Heap block at 000001C207A21D60 modified at
>   000001C207A21DA5 past requested size of 35

The code invokes the following error in a **Win32** build:

> HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#93) at 0x00636110. CRT
>   detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap
>   buffer.

The malloc line is wrong. It should be modified like this:

```
void** p = (void**)malloc(1*sizeof(void*));
```

Because the sizeof a pointer is `sizeof(void*)` bytes, not one byte!